# With fixed k>=4, can 3-coloring in a graph of vertex degree at most k be solved in polynomial time?

Tags: graphs, np-complete, reductions, colorings

I couldn't think of a poly-time solution. Moreover, I think that there is a pretty simple Karp-reduction from 3-coloring problem, which is NP-complete.

let's say that graph G is in 3-colloring.
I'll build G' in the following fashion:

every vertex with a degree >= k I'll split (as many as needed) by adding one neighbor and a "duplication" of itself with the rest of the original neighbors, thus if 3-coloring is possible in graph G, then a 3-coloring is possible in G' as well.

For example, for a max degree of 6:

(8 neighbors)-(v) in G will be -> (6 neigbhors)-(v)-(u)-(v-duplication)-(2 neighborhs) in G'.

vertex u is added so the 3-coloring in G can remain as well in G'.

Would love to hear your feedback on the reduction or if you know a poly time algorithm by any chance that solves the 3-coloring in a graph of a bounded degree.

Comment: Every (finite) graph has bounded vertex degree.  Apparently, you meant "suppose $k$ is fixed. Is 3-coloring on a graph of vertex degree at most $k$ an NP-complete problem?". By the way, 3-coloring on a graph of degree at most 3 can be done in linear time. So you may want to require $k\ge4$. Please update the question to clarify.

Comment: @JohnL. Thanks, you're correct. updated the question.

Comment: How do you ensure that the same color is assigned all copies of the same vertex?

Comment: I'm not, but by duplicating and adding a vertex in between duplications I can make sure that in the new graph they can have the same color. so a 3COL coloring exists. 
Maybe I did the reduction wrong, but that is my thinking @Steven

Comment: PS in case someone is wondering, the reason why 3-coloring on a graph of maximal degree 3 is in linear time is by application of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem ; see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/52182 for explanations.